# Can't fully automate the creating and opening p5.js project in atom with batch file

Tags: batch-file, atom-editor, p5.js

I created the `p5.js` project with `p5 -manager` tool. I successfully automated the whole thing with a batch file.

I should be able to open sketch.js with atom using additional batch script on the same file. But nothing happens and also no errors shows up. But same script on seperate file works just fine.

```
set /p PROJECT_NAME="Enter project Name: "
cd /d i:\My Work\p5
p5 generate --bundle %PROJECT_NAME% 
atom "I:\My Work\p5\%PROJECT_NAME%\sketch.js"
```

the last line seem not to be working here.

but if I write:

```
set /p PROJECT_NAME="Enter project Name: "
atom "I:\My Work\p5\%PROJECT_NAME%\sketch.js"
```

on a seperate file and run it with valid folder name, it runs and opens atom with sketch.js file.

here `PROJECT_NAME` variable is the name of the project and the folder that is created with that name.

I think i guessed what it is. the `p5 generate` command runs which closes the command prompt before the next line runs. cause even the `pause` and `cmd /d` command are not doing anything if i put them after `p5 generate` line. Do you know how can i prevent it from closing and forcing it to run the next lines?

Comment: Can you show an example of `Project_name`? How this cannot be working? Is this an invalid path?

Comment: i just input an project name like- hello

Comment: and it creates p5 projetc on I:\My Work\p5\hello directory

Comment: then i input hello on a seperate scipt file writting hello as input. then it opens

Comment: This is the whole batch file? Also, is this code inside a parenthesized block or somewhere else or just there?

Comment: but not on the same scipt file. same line same variable.

Comment: this is the whole exact script on a .bat file.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain [edit]ing your question what `p5` and what `atom` do, linking to their documentation pages? Since I am not familiar with them, this will help me.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5-manager

Comment: p5-manager creates project folder with all necessary files like index.html and sketch.js. and adds all the library files. p5 is the command for it. atom is command for opening atom from command line saving me the trouble to copy  and paste them. atom is text

Comment: `p5 generate --bundle projectNameGoesHare` is the command that you type in. while being in the directory(cd) you want to put create the project   in.

Comment: When you open `cmd.exe` can you do `where atom` and show me the output? I suggest you put full path to atom file, including extenstion. i.e `"C:\program files\atom\atom.exe" "I:\My Work\p5\%PROJECT_NAME%\sketch.js"` Also ensure your script name is not called `atom.cmd` or `atom.bat`

Comment: its in `AppData\local\atom\bin` i dont know how to copy from cmd.

Comment: `c:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\local\atom\bin\atom.cmd` and `c:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\local\atom\bin\atom` are the output

Comment: `set /p PROJECT_NAME="Enter project Name: "
cd /d I:\My Work\p5
p5 generate --bundle %PROJECT_NAME%
"C:\program files\atom\atom.exe" "I:\My Work\p5\%PROJECT_NAME%\sketch.js"` i ran and same thing.

Comment: and i named gd.cmd. was not atom.cmd before.

Comment: is the problem in using PROJECT_NAME variable twice or could it be i am using it inside a dir path string `"I:\My Work\p5\%PROJECT_NAME%\sketch.js"

Comment: I think i guessed what it is. the `p5 generate` command closes the cmd before the next line runs. cause even the `pause` and `cmd /d` command are not doing anything if i put them after `p5 generate` 
 line. Do you know how can i prevent it from closing and forcing it to run the next lines?

Comment: Please put all relevant information into the question by [edit]ing it! Postingh tons of comments is just terrible...

Comment: @aschipfl i was replying to someone. it was a discussion.

Comment: Well, comments are not intended for discussions, that's what chats are for. Anyway, another user was requesting more information that is relevant to your question; that's why I commented. Regard that comments may become cleaned up, so the information is gone; putting it in the question could make it helpful for other users also in future...

Comment: Oh ! Did not know that. Only been in this forum two questions. Thanx for telling.@aschipfl

Comment: I added in the edit of the question that one of the line is closing the cmd window before the later lines run. Which might be the problem . I will ask it as seperate question may be.